# Searching for a movie name

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am trying to implement the search function on a table in the database which contains only movies.

```
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String originalTitle;
    
    private String year;

    private String trailer;
    ....etc
```

The search is based mainly on the name, but I am not sure which would be the best option to use, based on differences which can occur.

For ex. some user can search for "Wall E", some will search for "Wall-E" but my database contains the original name "WALL·E".

I stopped at two options: to build a regex and use it when I search the database, and Elastic search with Fuzzy Matching.

Which would be the best to use in this scenario, and what else should I take into account regarding performance and false-positives?

I am using Spring Boot for the backend and MySQL as a database.

Comment: what is your DB?

Comment: I am using MySQL. Forgot to add it, will edit the question now, sorry!